# If x is incremented after (x++), would y print out = or will it print out +1?

Tags: java

```
x = 2; 
y = x++; 
System.out.println(y)
```

If x is incremented after, would y print out 2 or will it print out 3 and why?
If this was prefixed, would it print out just the 3?

Comment: [Why don't you try?](http://ideone.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plus signs is after the variable it called a post-increment. If the was before the variable it would be called a pre-increment. With pre-increments y would be assigned x+1. where as with the post-increment y would be assigned x then x would increment by one and there after be 3 but y would be 2.

x = 2;
y = x++;

with that y would be 2 and x would be 3.

x = 2;
y = ++x;

with that x,y would both be 3.

Answer (score 2):

It will print 2 and why it happens is

```
y=x++;
```

Step 1:

```
assign x value to y
```

Step 2:(increment x value)

```
x= x+1;
```

This is why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

it first assignes value to `y` & then increments `x` by `1`.

this is a `post increment`.
 this first assigns value to the left side variable of `=` & then increments right side variable `x` by 1.
here `y=2`, but `x=3`